# How to set Indian standard time in php?

Tags: php, sql, date, time, opencart

I'm using PHP codeigniter so here I want to get current national time. 
I tried    `NOW()`  in my sql code but when server change the location the server time changes. if I give `date()` it will take our system current time I think. in `date()`case if some user have some wrong date time then it will store that wrong time. So how can I solve this problem.

Comment: May this helps you : http://www.opencartnews.com/tutorials/how-to-change-opencart-timezone/

Comment: In the first place, why would anyone, who was given access rights in your server, intentionally change the location that caused the change in server time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set default timezone to India in the starting of the php code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

**the query**

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO oc_customer SET date_added = ' ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ." ' ";
```

Comment: I tried like this but phpinfo takes server located datetime and also i tried in httaccess also but not getting .

Comment: can you post the query ?

Comment: INSERT INTO oc_customer SET  date_added =NOW()

Comment: try 
 $query = "INSERT INTO oc_customer SET date_added = ' ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ." ' ";  

and in the starting of the php file 

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

Answer (score 5):

in your project index.php just put following code at line no 2

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

or check timezone here

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Comment: server taking its default time zone when I tried like this.

Comment: try echo date_default_timezone_get() in your welcome view or any view.

Answer (score 2):

Placing this `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');` Put it in **config/config.php**, It will work for whole application

**OR**

Add this line to autoload.php in the application folder:

```
$autoload['time_zone'] = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

**OR**

Add this line inside the main **index.php** of codeigniter folder

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Answer (score 2):

Few clarity,

`date_default_timezone_set` does not have any effect on sql `NOW()`.

Also, server date/time does not depend on users' system unless you are fetching it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of timezones PHP Provides, so eventually codeigniter does
[PHP Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Here is the way where you can list out timezones in CI and can use further.

```
$timezones =  DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);

 foreach ($timezones as $timezone) 
 {
    echo $timezone;
    echo "</br>";
 }
```

Also maybe by researching I have found the way is by keeping in `config.php` file.

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```